# What psychiatric and psychological tests do people need to pass to become astronauts?

Tags: astronauts, health, testing, medical, astronaut-recruitment

I am writing a short film about an astronaut during re-entry to earth. Part of the conflict I wrote is that the astronaut could not pass the mental tests required. Could anyone tell me any tests people need to pass before going to space?

Specifically if possible: *How does NASA determine if a person can maintain control and focus during very stressful situations?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a039228.pdf) (images too sloppy to copy text from)

[image]
[image]

The link has some statistical results.

A more recent (1985) description can be found on pages 23-25 of this [paper](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a154051.pdf); again, the text is not readily copy-able.  It does say, in reference to the Mercury tests

> The  15  tests  used  for  astronaut  selection primarily  examined 
>   the  neuropsychological  and  personality  traits  of the  applicants.
>   A  multi-modal  approach,  using  self-report,  projective 
>   techniques  and  biochemical  assays,  was  employed  to  obtain  only
>   the  most  qualified  astronauts  and  to  eliminate  individuals 
>   having psychopathologies  (Flinn  et  al.,  1963).

Comment: Are these still the standard nowadays?  I don’t see how a rorschach test would be helpful at all.  I’m also baffled by what a “draw a person test” might reveal to make it psychologically relevant to space flight.

Comment: @Paul What are your qualifications for drawing up a battery of tests for astronaut candidates?

Comment: Absolutely none! :). That’s why I ask.  I’m curious to know the motivations for the various  tests.

Comment: The mercury tests were a bit overblown, because it was a novel environment nobody knew what to expect to they did every test in the book. Nowdays it isn't as stringent but I would love to see the criteria for one of my own book projects.